# how to connect to mysql database using Phalanger on visual studios?

Tags: php, visual-studio, phalanger

i installed Phalanger 3.0 on visual studios, the php is working fine but how to create database and connect to database ? where to put config & Web.Config file ?

Answer (score 0):

With Phalanger you'll connect to MySQL in the same way as in PHP (the PHP code is the same).

The only thing you have to do, is to enable MySQL extension in application configuration. I recommend to download this one implemented in C# for best performance and 64bit abilities: http://phalangermysql.codeplex.com/releases/view/86375 .

Following is standard .NET configuration:

1. DLLs in the package can be simply copied into /Bin folder of your web app, or installed into global assembly cache.
2. web.config file has to be in the root of your web app.
3. copy following into web.config, `<configuration><phpNet><classLibrary>`:

   `<add assembly="PhpNetMySql, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2771987119c16a03" section="mysql"/>`

Let me know how does it work for you, Thanks!